# JAX-WS Soap converts String... to List<String>

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, soap, jax-ws

I am creating a WebService in Java using JAXWS
I have the following interface webmethod:

```
@WebMethod
public boolean check(String... p);
```

When i build and run the project, this is what the web service reference function looks like:

```
public boolean check(
    @WebParam(name = "arg0", targetNamespace = "")
    List<String> arg0)
    throws IllegalAccessException_Exception,
           InvocationTargetException_Exception,
            NoSuchMethodException_Exception;
```

The `String...` got replaced with `List<String>`
Now my question is:

#### How do i prevent JAXWS from converting my parameters from `String...` to `List<String>`

Comment: What else would you want it to convert to?

Comment: Just keep it `String...`

Comment: I get errors if i try calling the function with multiple strings as parameters. (varargs)

Comment: Would you share the failing sample code to call the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String...` (varargs) are basically arrays internally, the only difference is the code that you call it with. Like in main method, you can write `main(String... args)` instead of `main(String[] args)`.

JAX-WS uses generics, so that's why it converts your vararg parameter to list, since it's just a normal array.

If you really want to use array (vararg) parameter then you will need to write your own adapter and annotate the paramter with `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(YourAdapter.class)` where `YourAdapter` extends the `XmlAdapter<List<String>, String[]>` and overrides both marshall and unmarshall methods. I'm not sure if this will work with parameter (only remember it working with return value), you would have to test it, but I suggest just staying with list parameter.